# SQL Server LEN/DATALENGTH always returning 8000 for text column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working in 2008R2 currently, but I've got an audit table, tAudit, that was created in SQL Server 2000, I believe. Among others, tAudit has a text column called Change.  There's over 200k rows in tAudit.

I need to find the max length of the text contained in the Change column, but LEN and DATALENGTH both report 8000 characters for every row.  A sample of visual inspections suggests that the max length is more likely in the 200 to 300 character range.

Things I've tried:

-- All 236645 rows are 8000. What is going on here?

```
SELECT max(DATALENGTH(CAST(change AS VARCHAR(MAX)))), COUNT(*) AS MaxLenCount FROM dbo.tAudit
SELECT max(DATALENGTH(change)), COUNT(*) AS MaxLenCount FROM dbo.tAudit
SELECT max(LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(CAST(change AS VARCHAR(MAX)))))), COUNT(*) AS MaxLenCount 
FROM dbo.tAudit

CREATE TABLE #tAuditTemp 
(
     TaskID INT
   , AuditDate DATETIME
   , CHANGE varchar(8000) 
)
INSERT INTO #tAuditTemp
   SELECT 
        JobID
      , AuditDate
      , Change
   FROM dbo.tAudit 
   ORDER BY 
        AuditDate
      , JobID
      , cast(Change AS VARCHAR(max))

SELECT max(LEN(change)) AS MaxLen FROM #tAuditTemp  -- All are 8000 again; so much for the VAR part of VARCHAR in this case.
```

Specifying anything less than 8000 for Change in the temp table results in a truncation error at runtime.

I've also tried using CHARINDEX to locate the end of the string, but the Change values don't have sufficient commonality in the last few characters of the string that CHARINDEX does me any good.

The table was created with ANSI_PADDING ON. Capturing some Change data from the SSMS row editor shows that trailing blanks have not been stored.

Questions:
    1. Any idea why the length of 8000 would be reported for every row?
    2. Any idea how the actual lengths of the Change data can be extracted?

Comment: What is `min(len(change))`?

Comment: can you provide output of following query `SELECT * from #tAuditTemp where LEN(change) >= 7000`?

Comment: SELECT MIN(LEN(change)) from #tAuditTemp = 27

Comment: SELECT * from #tAuditTemp where LEN(change) >= 7000
yields 295 rows
Now we're getting somewhere.  
Can't use LEN on the Change TEXT datatype column, but as a VARCHAR(MAX) in #tAuditTemp, LEN works,

Answer (score 1):

char type is always padded with spaces to it's length (in your case 8000), you need to use varchar to prevent padding, you can also try to [TRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634558.aspx) to get actual text

here is from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

> char [ ( n ) ]
>
> ```
> Fixed-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and must be a value from 1 through 8,000
> ```

or you can turn off padding

> If SET ANSI_PADDING is OFF when either CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE is
>   executed, a char column that is defined as NULL is handled as varchar.

**UPDATE:**

I suppose you have at least 1 row with actual length 8000, which is why max returned it, if you want to calculate number of rows with different length, you can use:

```
SELECT LEN(change) as ChangeLength, COUNT(*) as LengthCount
FROM dbo.tAudit
GROUP BY LEN(change)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: ’Len’ doesn't count trailing spaces.

Comment: Just look for the documentation for `len` in books online. It will definitely mention it.

Comment: [Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression, **excluding trailing blanks**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith yep, I've mixed with db2, where you have to do trim

Comment: Had to use the temp table to get at the VARCHAR(MAX) version of Change, but this slightly tweaked query works:
SELECT LEN(change) as ChangeLength, COUNT(*) as LengthCount
FROM dbo.#tAuditTemp
GROUP BY LEN(change)
ORDER BY 1 desc
You're right, Lashane there was actually 217 rows with a len of 8000. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Questions:
   1. Any idea why the length of 8000 would be reported for every row?
   2. Any idea how the actual lengths of the Change data can be extracted?

The Answers:
   1. Because I was so wrapped up in the difficulties of dealing with a TEXT field, I didn't pay attention to the fact
that the MAX was left over from the copy/paste in the three original queries at the top of this page.  Lashane's 
`"SELECT LEN(change) as ChangeLength, COUNT( * ) as LengthCount..."` 
pointed me to my (obvious) problem.  
   2. Tweaking the query referenced above to use the temp table instead of tAudit allowed me to get the needed 
results. Also, however, without the spurious MAX, I was also able to get the desired result directly from tAudit using

`SELECT LEN(CAST(change AS VARCHAR(MAX))) as ChangeLength, COUNT(*) as LengthCount
   FROM dbo.tAudit
   GROUP BY LEN(CAST(change AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
   ORDER BY 1 desc`  
Thanks to everyone who contributed!

Answer (score -1):

There are no CHAR columns involved here.  The issue is that a TEXT column always shows a length of 8000, irrespective of the actual length of the string, and no padding spaces have been stored.  ANSI_PADDING ON *allows* trailing spaces to be stored, but again, that is not the case here, as none of the rows I have inspected have even one trailing space.

Comment: You do visual inspection so I guess your are being conceived by the hidden spaces at the end of CHANGE field. Try updating the data with the trimmed version.